# When trying to login to Google's OAuth 2.0 in embedded webviews users get disallowed_useragent

Tags: web, mobile, webview, google-oauth

We are advertising our product on Facebook and Linkedin. When users click on our ads, a webview opens with an opinion for Google SSO as a sign-up option. We support only webview at the moment.
The Google OAuth as a sign-up/login mechanism works on desktop and mobile, but when the site opens inside a mobile app such as Facebook, the user gets this error shown.

[image]

the error leads to: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#authorization-errors-disallowed-useragent

As I understand Google wants us to set 2 configuration files in our site route directory, "apple-app-site-association.json" file for iPhone and "AndroidManifest.xml" for android.
I'm trying to configure them, but I don't understand how to without a mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected due to security changes to Google's OAuth 2.0 authorization endpoint, you can find more details [here](https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/upcoming-security-changes-to-googles-oauth-2.0-authorization-endpoint.html)